# how to trigger jquery event when dropdown selection changes via model

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, razor

I have a list of names with an edit button next to it.
When the edit button is clicked, the actionresult loads a partial for edit and fills in the name in an textbox.
On this partial I also have a drop down list that shows a list of file names of images.
I have jquery code for the change event to show a little image of the selected one.
When I change the drop down selection, that works just fine.
But when I click on the edit button and the name is filled in the textbox and the selection of the dropdown is set via the model, the change event is not triggered.

Is it possible to trigger a change event on a drop down list if the selection changes but not by the user?

Can you trigger a jquery function within an @if (...) {...} line in the razor.

For example:

```
@if (m=>m.image.length >0)
{
   //do something here to trigger the change event of the drop down list
}
```

any help would be great!!

Answer (score 1):

I don't feel that there is an need to invoke a javadcropt event inside an if condition.what you could do the document load finish event you can do the rendering of image based of selection. Something like this :

```
$(function (){
  var selection = $(#'youdropdownid').val ();
  //do the things based on the value.
```

});

Another way would be to trigger a event handler on an element like following :

```
$( "#yourdropdownd" ).trigger( "change" );
```

Although I feel that manually invoking event handler would be quite unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can do something like:

```
@if (m=>m.image.length > 0){  
    <script> 
        $( "#dropdownlist" ).trigger("change");   
    </script> 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working by combining the two suggestions from Felix and Qamar.

I have already Jquery code on the index page where the partials are part of.
I placed the the trigger code behind that script:

```
@section Scripts 
{
  <script>
    $(function () 
    {
      'use strict';

      $('#cbImages').on('change', function () {
      var imgurl = $('#cbImages :selected').val();

      if (imgurl != '') 
      {
        $('#imgPhoto').attr('src', '/PowerConnectorImages/' + imgurl);
        $('#imgPhoto').show();
      } 
      else 
      {
        $('#imgPhoto').hide();
      }
    });
  });
  </script>

  @if (Model.PowerConnector.ImageName != null)
  {
    if (Model.PowerConnector.ImageName.Length > 0)
    {
      <script>
        $(function () 
        {
          $('#cbImages').trigger('change');
        });
      </script>
    }
  }
}
```

I has to be behind because the change event code needs to exist first.

thanks for the suggestions!